# Edit some files in resources folder after production in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

I am trying to edit some files (for example change the path of logo file) in resources folder in laravel project. After editing files which needed website is not updated.

I used :

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache 
php artisan cache:clear
```

but nothing helped. changes are not updated. Maybe I need to run some commands from ssh and make edition?

Comment: try `php artisan optimize` and/or  `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: _for example change the path of logo file_ It could be your brower's cache. Try hard refreshing the cache of the page from your browser.

Comment: @Abdulla Nilam ,  after running `php artisan optimize` I see this error :

  `LogicException  : Unable to prepare route [api/ip/info] for serialization.`

but running `composer dump-autoload` succesfully finishes without any error. Now will try with this command whether it works or not.

Comment: `composer dump-autoload` did not help.

Comment: @AliMammadov if you see that error there is a mistake in defining a route (api/ip/info), the command optimize clears and rebuilds the route cache. composer dump-autoload? that only updates the autoload for the vendor folder, and would not fix anything

Comment: Could you give an example of what exactly you changed? If it's just path of the logo you changed, is the URL not reflected? If so, try `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: @sykez, for example in the website when you login there is word "Hi, yournickname". The related file is in : `/home/username/appfolder/resources/containers/Sidebar/components/UserMenu/index.js`  : 
`<FormattedMessage defaultMessage="Hi, {name}"        id="common.user_greeting" values={{ name : <b>{auth.user.name}</b> }}/>`

For example I want to change the word "Hi" to "Bye" (just an example). after changing and saving it whatever I do it doesn't change on website.

Comment: `php artisan view:clear`  - this command did not work

Comment: @GertB. so you mean the only possible way to make it work (to make it updated) is to run the command : `php artisan optimize` ? and this commands make an error in my server. what a complex system it is..

Comment: `/home/username/appfolder/resources/containers/Sidebar/components/UserMenu/index.js` Strongly looks like that your javascript that needs to be rebuilt

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier what does that mean ? can you explain a bit more? My question is not about my javascript it is about I can not update the changes.

Comment: Javascript files generaly needs to be built. Assuming you're using default, you will probably have to run `npm run prod`

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier you are absolutely right. I have never built the javascript files. I have never used that command `npm run prod` but what is interesting everything works as expected. if i never built it then how it works ? 

when I try to build the javascript files I get an error : 

`> @ production /home/coins/coins
> cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

error: unknown option '--no-progress'`

Comment: @AliMammadov its not complex, php artisan optimize clears & builds all the caches. if you have errors in your route files that throws an error. fix the api/ip/info route, and that command will work